# Trouble saving scroll position in Chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scroll

I'm relatively new to programming and am working on a Chrome extension with a popup. I want to save the scroll position between popup invocations. It seems like I've found a lot of info on the internet, but so far I haven't been able to solve my problem. Saving the scroll position almost works within my extension, but I'm seeing 2 issue:

**1)** To save the scroll position at each scroll event, I use:

```
addEventListener('scroll', function(){
   localStorage.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
});
```

When the popup is opened, I use:

```
document.body.scrollTop = localStorage.scrollTop
```

This seems to work fine until my scroll position exceeds the popup height. The max popup height for visible content in a Chrome extension is 600px. `document.body.style.height` is also always a fixed value greater than 600px. When the scroll position is greater than `document.body.style.height` - 600px, say 900px - 600px, `document.body.scrollTop` is reset to 300px. Even if the last scroll position (`document.body.scrollTop`) was 400px before the popup is closed, scroll position is reset to 300px when the popup is re-opened. Obviously, I get the wrong scroll position because the proper scroll position value of 400px (for example) is then overwritten by 300px.

However, it doesn't always happen. Sometimes I can properly save a scroll position of, say 500px with a window height of 900px, and other times I can't. I don't know for sure why this has any effect, but as the content in the popup is taller the problem seems to magically go away and the proper scroll position is saved.

How can I properly save the scroll position when the scroll position in this situation? Perhaps I'm doing something fundamentally wrong?

(This seems confusing to read. I hope it's possible to help with the code above.)

**2)** I think might be intertwined with the above issue, but I'm not sure. For every scroll event (first code block in this post), I see a pair of scroll events fired.

If I just open the popup but don't scroll the mousewheel, I see code inside my event listener fire. When the first event happens, `document.body.scrollTop` is reset to the "wrong" value (300px in the example above). I think this might be the root cause of both issues.

Shouldn't the event listener only fire if the mousewheel is moved, and thus the code inside the event listener doesn't execute if the popup is opened but the mousewheel isn't touched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was actually in the corresponding CSS code. The `<div>` wasn't scrollable, and so it didn't allow saving a scroll position bigger than the visible area of the popup.

The solution was to add the `position: relative;` and `overflow-y: auto;` (`overflow-y: scroll;` works as well) properties to the CSS element.

Once those properties were added, I could properly save the scroll position to an object.

Answer (score 0):

I know this shouldn't be an answer, but I can't format code in a comment:

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest you try test one of the basic assumptions:  **Are the scroll events firing in order?**

Try this, see if adds some useful debugging info:

```
var scrollCounter = 0;
addEventListener('scroll', function(){
   localStorage.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
   console.log({counter: scrollCounter, scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop});
   scrollCounter++
})
```

See if the numbers seem to jump around, or if they go in progressive order.

**Edit:  P-code for a possible solution**

I think I have an idea for a `fix`, though I use the word fix kind of loosely here.

```
var captureSemaphore; // Use this to flag exactly when we want the `scrollTop` captured.
captureSemaphore = true; // Go into catch mode

addEventListener('scroll', function(){
   if (captureSemaphore) {
     localStorage.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
});

// then later, right before you open your popup
captureSemaphore = false; // Disable catch mode because the screen is about to change
openPopup();              // Open the popup

// Elsewhere

closePopup();            // Close the popup
captureSemaphore = true; // Go into catch mode
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding your suggestion, and it turns out that simply opening the popup fires off 2 events (counter goes to 1). As before, `document.body.scrollTop` is still being reset to 300px. If I open the popup and scroll down in 100px increments, the first 2 are both at 300px, but then I get one event at 400px, one event at 500px, etc. So that part seems to be working fine. The key appears to be figuring out why the height of the content in the popup matters - with certain content heights everything works fine. Arrgh!

Comment: Ah! That brings me to another idea.  Put a watch on the `resize` event.  I'll bet that opening the popup causes a `resize` which in turn affects `scrollTop` or something.

Comment: Yes, I think the popup is being resized. Using `window.onresize = resizeHandler;`, the function is called every time the popup is opened. Even if I don't interact with the popup, the code inside the `resizeHandler()` is called once when the popup is invoked. This happens with the content height means scroll position is properly saved or not. Does this help explain what's going on? Even if this isn't the fix, thank you for this great learning moment!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I don't think this will work. The scroll event itself is triggered twice, so as long as the popup is open adding a mutex has no effect.

Comment: Afraid I've taken you as far as I can then.  Hope the data I helped you collect points you towards at answer/workaround at least.